# How to find out how many items in a dataframe is within a certain range?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm currently doing some analysis on the stats of my podcast, and I have merged my Spotify listening numbers with the ones from my RSS-feed in pandas. So far so good, I now have a dataframe with a column of "Total" which tells me how many listeners I had on each episode and what the average number of listeners is.

Now, what I want to do is to see how many of my episodes fit in to three categories (at least), Good, Normal and Bad. So I need to divide my Totals into three ranges and then see how many of my episodes land within each of those frames. I have some limited experience of messing around with Python and pandas, but it's been a while since I last sat down with it and I dont really know how to approach this problem.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What did you try till now?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: I might have found something now. I tried:
evaluation = pd.qcut(listens.Total, 3, labels=["Bad", "Normal", "Good"])

But I'm not sure if it does what I want it to. I now have a list of evalutations, and I guess that the qcut divided the range of listens into three parts. I should be able to find a way to sort out each evaluation and get the amount. 

Am I on the right track, or do you see anything wrong with it immidiately?